# Can someone explain what's happening with this code?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
    int *b = a - 1;

    printf("%d \n",*(a+2));
}
```

I know that it prints `30` which is same as `a[2]`, but how?
What does `a - 1` do  to the the array `a[]`?

Comment: You're not using `b` variable, so that whole line can be ignored...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a - 1` does not change `a`, in the same way that `3 + 2` does not change `3`.

This code causes undefined behaviour because `a - 1` tries to form a pointer outside of the bounds of `a`. But in practice it is likely that the `b` line will just be ignored, so your code will behave the same as:

```
int a[] = {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};
printf("%d \n",*(a+2));
```

which of course prints `30`.

Comment: Ok. So, there's no difference between printing `*(a+2)` and `a[2]`, right? Just like printing either `*a`, `*(a+1)`, `*(a+2)` , `*(a+3)`.. and `a[0]`, `a[1]`, `a[2]`, `a[3]`.. are same?

Comment: @Ishtiaq Yes `x[y]` is defined to mean `*(x+y)` .